# Connecting Calendar control to LINQ database - Visual Studio

Tags: database, vb.net, linq, datetime, calendar

I have 2 calender controls 'cldStartDate' and 'cldEndDate' which link to 2 textboxes 'txtStartDate' and 'txtEndDate.  When a date is selected these textboxes hold the dates.  I am trying to get my code to add the dates into my database.  It has the following fields:

-ProjectName
-Description
-StartDate
-EndDate

Both 'StartDate' and 'EndDate' are of type DateTime in my database.  Could someone please point out where I am going wrong in my code.  I think I need to change the code to pass the date values in as DateTime.  Has anyone got an idea of how I may do that.  The code is below.  Thanks!

Protected Sub btnAddProject_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles btnAddProject.Click

```
    Dim projectName As String
    Dim projectDescription As String
    Dim startdate As String
    Dim enddate As String

    projectName = txtProjectName.Text
    projectDescription = txtProjectName.Text
    startdate = txtStartDate.Text
    enddate = txtEndDate.Text

    ' check the validity of information entered
    Dim isValid As Boolean
    isValid = True

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(projectName) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(projectDescription)     Then
        isValid = False
    End If

    If isValid Then
        'add everything to the database
        Dim db As New AgileClassesDataContext()

        Dim startDate As String
        startDate = DateTime.Parse(startDate)

        Dim endDate As String
        endDate = DateTime.Parse(endDate)

        ' create a project to populate a row in the PROJECT table
        Dim project As New Project With _
        {.ProjectName = projectName, _
         .Description = projectDescription _
         .StartDate = startdate _
         .EndDate = enddate}

        ' add the new project to the PROJECT table
        db.Projects.InsertOnSubmit(project)

        ' submit the changes to the database
        Try
            db.SubmitChanges()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex)
            db.SubmitChanges()
        End Try'
```

Comment: You haven't told us anything about what's actually *wrong* at the moment.

Comment: Haha woops. Basically the project will not compile.  With the following code I get errors.

'Dim startDate As String
  startDate = DateTime.Parse(startDate)

   Dim endDate As String
   endDate = DateTime.Parse(endDate)

   Dim project As New Project With _
        {.ProjectName = projectName, _
         .Description = projectDescription _
         .StartDate = startdate _
         .EndDate = enddate}'
It says that 'StartDate' and 'EndDate' are not members of string. In my database they are 'DateTime' fields so I am not sure of how to enter the selected dates into these fields in the database

Comment: <sigh> Right, so you've got errors. But you've decided not to tell us what those errors are. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question *thoroughly*.

Comment: Sorry Jon.  I'm new to SO as you probably guessed.  I have posted a, hopefully clearer message as an answer.  My problem is that I get a "StartDate is not a member of string" error and the same for EndDate.  In the database table they are DateTime fields.  I have a calender control which passes the date to a text box, 'txtStartDate'.  I want to pass the value from here into to 'StartDate' field in my DB.  I appreciate any advice and apologise for the poor way this is being written.  Thanks

Comment: No, don't add an answer, edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *suspect* the immediate problem is your syntax for the object initializer. Instead of this:

```
Dim project As New Project With _
    {.ProjectName = projectName, _
     .Description = projectDescription _
     .StartDate = startdate _
     .EndDate = enddate}
```

... you should have a comma after each property:

```
Dim project As New Project With { _
    .ProjectName = projectName, _
    .Description = projectDescription, _
    .StartDate = startdate, _
    .EndDate = enddate }
```

Comment: Thank you.  I added the comas, which have gotten rid of the error I was getting.  However I now have "Variable startDate hides a variable in an enclosing block"  This is also happening for "endDate".  This refers to the code section 

     'Dim startDate As String
      startDate = DateTime.Parse(startDate)

      Dim endDate As String
      endDate = DateTime.Parse(endDate)'

Comment: Dammit.  The code does not seem to format correctly in the comments.

Comment: @Gavin: Right, yes, it would. So you'll need to use different variable names for the text version and the parsed version. Follow the compiler errors messages. (Any reason you're using a textbox for this rather than a date picker control of some kind?)

Comment: Jon - I changed the variable names, compiled and tested and it passes the values into the database.  Thank you very very much for your help.  It is greatly appreciated.  Have a great day